# LongListSelector - Changing the colour of the current selected item

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, longlistselector

I have a weird situation.
I have a longlistselector with MVVM databinding. When one item get's selected, I change the colour of the text to the phone accent colour. But the item doesn't change its colour on the screen. ( even not when I scroll in the list )
If I then just switch to another page and come back, the item colour is changed if I scroll to it if it is not visible. If it is visible, it still hasn't changed colour until I scroll it out of view and back into view, then the colour will also change.

Anyone the same experience?

Comment: How are you changing the color?

Comment: On my model I have a property "Brush SelectedColour" and I change that for the selected item in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing a bound value but it's not being reflected in the UI then this will typically indicate that you're not correctly notifying of the change. Make sure you're implementing `INotifyPropertyChanegd` on the viewmodel and calling `RaisePropertyChanged` appropriately.

Comment: Hey Matt, it's bound with mvvm-light, that framework does raise the changes automatically.

Comment: @Depechie mvvm-light does not raise the changes automatically, it just makes it easier for you to do it if your viewmodels inherit from `ViewModelBase`.

Comment: ha? Maybe I'm missing something then? So if I databounded a collection to the list (the prop in the viewmodel has RaisePropertyChanged and is the collection), how would I signal one item it's colour change? I just changed the value and signaled the RaisePropertyChanged manually...

Comment: Other than manually calling the RaisePropertyChanged? ( because I'm doing that )

Comment: Matt I double checked everything! And I didn't do the PropertyChanged notification correctly! Thanks again for pointing me in the correct direction!